The goal of this ear training (voice leading) material
I came across this harmonic(voice leading) exercise that i've never seen it taught anywhere else AFAIK, and im not sure that i understand what this exercise is trying to achieve, or in what way does it help with transcribing.


What book is this from?

@phoog it is a book called "ear training workbook" from berklee i think

The point of the voice leading section is to develop the ability to follow a single voice through a harmonic progression.  If you are transcribing a piece played by an ensemble of voices and/or monophonic instruments, or even a homophonic texture played by a chordal instrument, identifying the harmony is fairly unimportant.  The most important skill is to be able to pick a particular voice or instrument from the texture and follow it.  Consider: if you transcribe each voice separately, you can subsequently derive the harmonic analysis from the resulting transcription.  But if you identify the chords accurately, you have no idea which voice is singing or playing which note apart from the bass.

Thanks for the explanation! One thing i noticed that when i am practicing the voice leading exercise is that, before i can sing the next note, my brain tend to hear the current chord's arppegio first, is this ok?

@juicyliberty sure.  I come to this sort of thing from conducting, where the goal is ultimately to be able to follow not just one voice but multiple voices.  Exercises for that include not only playing a four-part piece while singing one of the parts, or switching from part to part, but also playing just one part while singing another, which is more difficult for many people.  If you're hearing all the notes of a chord, you're already hearing more than many people do.  If hearing this as an arpeggio is getting in your way somehow, well, be patient with yourself and learn to overcome it.

When transcribing, it's often useful to begin with the lowest pitches, and these will often be chordal roots — particularly in popular music. The first portion of the exercise familiarizes the ear with the root motion of a chord progression as well as the sound of each individual chord. This can help a great deal in identifying the progression one is hearing and the quality of each chord in the progression.
The voice-leading portion of the exercise assists in hearing the relationships between chords. Further, since a great deal of music follows common-tone and stepwise voice leading, it teaches one what to listen for across the progression. This is particularly helpful when attempting to transcribe a particular instrument or musical line, because having identified an individual pitch, one can anticipate what is likely to come after (or before). The ability to anticipate can also help when the music doesn't follow the expected voice leading. Not hearing an expected pitch is a useful step in transcribing. And being able to hear/sing the arpeggio helps identify what pitch is actually ocurring.

Obviously, with understanding harmonies, it's of paramount importance to know which notes make up triads. Initially, the actual note names are academic, so call them solfege names, or simply numbers - as in chord I - do - me - so, or 1 - 3 - 5. In fact without this knowledge, there's no start point.
The next trick is to be capable of hearing the relationship between one chord and another - usually consecutives. So being able to recognise that the I chord has so as its 'highest' note, and that's the 'lowest' note of the V chord - in any key at all, is important for harmony analysis.
Once established, it's easier to sway around the component notes of each triad and recognise the relationships between those chords.
It's then apparent that other 'stray' notes - diatonic or not, will give clues to a different cadence, which is probably what that movement may be called.

This exercise makes a lot of sence for ear training as well as for voice leading. For best benefit you sing and play it vertically and horizontally. I would also practice in the same way the entire cadence:
I IV V I, the so called cadence canon:
Do Do Ti Do
So La So So
Mi Fa Re Mi
Do Fa So Do
I -  IV -  V - I

Although I haven't encountered this type of exercise myself before, I think this can be a quite effective exercise for the stated purpose: helping one to recognize chord progression.
I will actually try use this exercise to help my kids learn to recognize cadences since sometimes they are struggling to distinguish between I-V-I and I-IV-I cadences reliably when I spread around the notes in various inversions that they never heard before.  My approach has been to play lots of different I-V-I and I-IV-I cadences from different contexts, hoping that they will instinctively pick up the difference.
However, with this approach they can focus on the movement of individual notes belonging to each chord as each voice changes (or stays constant) in the progression.  As an added benefit beyond chord progression recognition, this exercise will give them examples of best practices on how to make smooth chord progression on the piano, let's say when harmonizing a hymn tune or working off a lead sheet.

Something that trips me up every now and then is the fact that both I-IV-I and I-V7-I have ^3-^4-^3 melodic motion.
